# Disable navigation drawer item, if it is already selected, otherwise drawer item should be enabled

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm using navigation drawer. Navigation Drawer contains elements/items (Like: feedback, report, settings, refresh) in it. When I clicked on an Item then according to selected option UI will get updated.

Problem is that: I selected an Item from Navigation drawer, then UI get updated. If again I selected same option then again all methods for updating UI get called.

What I want is, If user clicked again on same Item in navigation drawer, then background methods should not get called.

I tries to set clickable property false, but with that items become non clickable. I'm not able to select the item.

Suppose I selected Feedback option, then next time when I again open the drawer then feedback option should not get selected. Means, consecutively user should not able to select same option.

Added Code:: Adapter Class:

```
public class NavDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavDrawerItem> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public NavDrawerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        NavDrawerItem[] objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    NavDrawerItem menuItem = this.getItem(position);
    if (menuItem.getType() == NavMenuItem.ITEM_TYPE) {
        view = getItemView(convertView, parent, menuItem);
    } else {
        view = getSectionView(convertView, parent, menuItem);
    }
    return view;
}

public View getItemView(View convertView, ViewGroup parentView,
        NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem) {

    NavMenuItem menuItem = (NavMenuItem) navDrawerItem;
    NavMenuItemHolder navMenuItemHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_item, parentView,
                false);
        TextView labelView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.navmenuitem_label);
        ImageView iconView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.navmenuitem_icon);

        navMenuItemHolder = new NavMenuItemHolder();
        navMenuItemHolder.labelView = labelView;
        navMenuItemHolder.iconView = iconView;

        convertView.setTag(navMenuItemHolder);
    }

    if (navMenuItemHolder == null) {
        navMenuItemHolder = (NavMenuItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    navMenuItemHolder.labelView.setText(menuItem.getLabel());
    navMenuItemHolder.iconView.setImageResource(menuItem.getIcon());

    return convertView;
}

public View getSectionView(View convertView, ViewGroup parentView,
        NavDrawerItem navDrawerItem) {

    NavMenuSection menuSection = (NavMenuSection) navDrawerItem;
    NavMenuSectionHolder navMenuItemHolder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navdrawer_section,
                parentView, false);
        TextView labelView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.navmenusection_label);

        navMenuItemHolder = new NavMenuSectionHolder();
        navMenuItemHolder.labelView = labelView;
        convertView.setTag(navMenuItemHolder);
    }

    if (navMenuItemHolder == null) {
        navMenuItemHolder = (NavMenuSectionHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    navMenuItemHolder.labelView.setText(menuSection.getLabel());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return this.getItem(position).getType();
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return getItem(position).isEnabled();
}

private static class NavMenuItemHolder {
    private TextView labelView;
    private ImageView iconView;
}

private class NavMenuSectionHolder {
    private TextView labelView;
}
}
```

Activity Class::

```
 public class NavDrawerActivity extends AbstractNavDrawerActivity  {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if ( savedInstanceState == null ) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,  new MainFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
protected NavDrawerActivityConfiguration getNavDrawerConfiguration() {

    NavDrawerItem[] menu = new NavDrawerItem[] {
            NavMenuSection.create( 100, "Logged in user details"),
            //NavMenuItem.create(101,"List/Detail (Fragment)", "navdrawer_friends", true, this),
            //NavMenuItem.create(102, "Airport (AsyncTask)", "navdrawer_airport", false, this),
            //NavMenuSection.create(200, "General"),
            NavMenuItem.create(202, getResources().getString(R.string.nav_drawer_item_reports), (R.drawable.drawer_shadow), false, this),
            NavMenuItem.create(203, getResources().getString(R.string.nav_drawer_item_feedback), (R.drawable.drawer_shadow), false, this),
            NavMenuItem.create(204, getResources().getString(R.string.nav_drawer_item_settings), (R.drawable.drawer_shadow), false, this)};

    NavDrawerActivityConfiguration navDrawerActivityConfiguration = new NavDrawerActivityConfiguration();
    navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setMainLayout(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);
    navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerLayoutId(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setLeftDrawerId(R.id.left_drawer);
    navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setNavItems(menu);
    navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow);     
    navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerOpenDesc(R.string.drawer_open);
    navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setDrawerCloseDesc(R.string.drawer_close);
    navDrawerActivityConfiguration.setBaseAdapter(
        new NavDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.navdrawer_item, menu ));
    return navDrawerActivityConfiguration;
}

@Override
protected void onNavItemSelected(int id) {
    switch ((int)id) {
    case 202:

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment()).commit();

        break;
    case 203:
        //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new AirportFragment()).commit();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Friend", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

MenuItem interface::

```
public interface NavDrawerItem {

public int getId();
public String getLabel();
public int getType();
public boolean isEnabled();
public boolean updateActionBarTitle();
}
```

Implementated Class:

```
public class NavMenuItem implements NavDrawerItem {

public static final int ITEM_TYPE = 1 ;

private int id ;
private String label ; 
private int icon ;
private boolean updateActionBarTitle ;

private NavMenuItem() {
}

public static NavMenuItem create( int id, String label, int icon, boolean updateActionBarTitle, Context context ) {
    NavMenuItem item = new NavMenuItem();
    item.setId(id);
    item.setLabel(label);
    item.setIcon(icon);
    item.setUpdateActionBarTitle(updateActionBarTitle);
    return item;
}

@Override
public int getType() {
    return ITEM_TYPE;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public int getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean updateActionBarTitle() {
    return this.updateActionBarTitle;
}

public void setUpdateActionBarTitle(boolean updateActionBarTitle) {
    this.updateActionBarTitle = updateActionBarTitle;
}
}
```

Added code for drawer listener :

```
 private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        selectItem(position);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please throw some lights on your navigation drawer code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Need to maintain lastClicked position. if lastclicked element is same as current clicked element, then no need to do anything. If current position is different then update the lastClicked with current position.

```
private static int lastClicked = 0;

  private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if(lastClicked != position){
            selectItem(position);
        }
        lastClicked = position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad! But not a very good solution if you have a home page where you return to when back button is pressed from navigation drawer item. (Having the same problem here and looking for an answer.)

Comment: Could you please explain your problem. I'm not getting what do you mean by "if you have a home page where you return to whaen back button is pressed from nav drawer". because if drawer is open and i'm pressing a back button then drawer simply closed.